# What additional test cases can be included in my Unit Testing?

Tags: python, file, unit-testing

Given the following function `RhymeOrNot` with contains three parameters: a file defined as a string, the first word defined as a string, and the second word defined as a string. This function will return a boolean indicating whether or not the words rhyme. A word rhyme with another word if the last vowel and every word after are the same. Both words need to be in the file containing a dictionary of the word and their pronunciation. If neither words or in the file, return false.

Sample File Looks Similar To This:

```
PHOTOGRAPH  F OW1 T AH0 G R AE2 F
STAFF  S T AE1 F
```

Here is a Unit Test in Python to test the function

```
class TestRhyme(object):
    def Test(self):
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "CAT", "HAT") == True
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "PHOTOGRAPH", "STAFF") == True
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "TRAIN", "SUSTAIN") == True
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "GIRL", "BOY") == False
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "START", "HEART") == True
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "BERRY", "BUILD") == False
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "CLASS", "PASS") == True
```

Updated:

```
class TestRhyme(object):
    def Test(self):
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "CAT", "HAT") == True
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "PHOTOGRAPH", "STAFF") == True
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "TRAIN", "SUSTAIN") == True
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "GIRL", "BOY") == False
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "START", "HEART") == True
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "BERRY", "BUILD") == False
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "CLASS", "PASS") == True
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "", "") == False
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "", "HAPPY") == False
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "HARRYPOTTER", "BTW") == False
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "AIRPLANE", "") == False
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "ABCDE", "FGHJI") == False
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "air", "") == False
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "", "sofa") == False
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "&#116;&#114;&#97;&#105;&#110;", "&#102;&#108;&#121;") == False
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "chair", "declare") == True
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "slam", "ham") == True
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "StAiR", "PaIr") == True
        assert RhymeOrNot("dictionary.txt", "pen", "hen") == True
        assert RhymeOrNot("", "pen", "hen") == FileNotFoundError
        assert RhymeOrNot("def", "pen", "hen") == FileNotFoundError
```

What other additional test cases can I incorporate in my Unit Testing? I want to test every possible test cases out there that follows the function `RhymeOrNot`.

Comment: You need false *and* true versions of each class of test to verify it's actually working. For example, the tests for decoding HTML entities needs a `true` test. And I'm guessing it does not work with HTML entities. You're still lacking a Unicode test.

Answer (score 2):

These are all "happy path" tests. They all test when processing is normal. You need some tests for what happens when things go wrong. These should all throw meaningful exceptions to allow the user to know what's going on. Garbage in, error out.

The words...

- What happens with an empty string?
- What if a word isn't in the dictionary? (and make it clear you're testing that)
- What if there's Unicode?
- What if they aren't capitalized?
- What if they're not strings?
- Any tricky combinations? Like should `AE0` and `AE1` rhyme? (and make it clear that's what you're testing)
- What if the words are the same? (tests a possibly broken optimization)
- What if there's spaces?
- What if there's non-alphanumeric characters?
- What about numbers?

The dictionary...

- What if `dictionary.txt` cannot be opened?
- What if it's empty?
- What if it's not in the expected format?

Use a [coverage analysis tool](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/) to check that your tests touch every line of the code. Any lines you miss need a test.

Testing is the first time many interfaces are really used and they're a good time to find basic interface problems. You might find it annoying to generate a new file for each of these cases. This points out that `RhymeOrNot` is inflexible. It's wielded three separate operations together: reading a file, parsing it, checking the rhymes. They should be three separated.

You could instead have a `RhymingDictionary` object to store the parsed dictionary. It could be initialized in various ways: from a file, from any IO stream, one word at a time, and so on. All would be wrappers around the same parser method. Then you have a separate `rhyme_or_not` method that uses an initialized object.

Separating them allows you to more thoroughly test each of the three pieces of functionality: reading input, parsing input, checking rhymes. The flexibility makes it easier for you, and the users, to setup dictionaries. It improves performance of both the tests and production use by not having to reparse the potentially very large dictionary every time you check for a rhyme.

Comment: @Anonymous No. An error reading or parsing the dictionary file should [raise an exception](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Exceptions) specific to what went wrong. If it can't read the file the normal IO exception should be allowed to happen. If the file is malformatted it should raise an exception of your own indicating what happened and where in the file the problem is. You get to decide if an empty file is valid or not. If it is, proceed as normal. If it isn't, raise an exception.

Comment: Anymore that I am missing?

Comment: @Anonymous I'm not a Python person, but I don't think that's how exceptions work. I think you've mistaken Unicode for HTML entities. And you're still missing tests for an empty and malformatted file.